# While set up the Android Driver for the Selenium Grid I got the error "ANDROID_HOME" environment variable not set, anybody provide the solution

Tags: java, android, selenium, selenium-grid, selendroid

I have install the selenium grid successfully for the FF, chrome and IE now I want to install capabilities for the Android (using Selendroid) I got the following screenshot error 
[image]

Comment: Ya...status is not as per http://selendroid.io/setup.html#systemRequirements

Answer (score 3):

What you have to do is :

1. Check whether Java sdk (minimum 1.6) is installed and JAVA_HOME is configured.
2. Download Latest release from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
3. Set the Environment path:

   Set proper Environment path for Java

   Right Click on My Computer->Properties

   Select Advanced system Settings

   Click on Environment Variables

   Variable name : JAVA_HOME.

   Variable Value :C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\ (This should be the path of JDK on  the machine)

   Variable name : PATH .Variable Value :% JAVA_HOME%bin;
4. Latest Android-Sdk is installed

   Download ANDROID_SDK  from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
5. ANDROID_HOME is set.

   Variable name : ANDROID_HOME Variable Value : D:\InstalledSoftwares\ANDROID\

   Variable name : PATH .Variable Value :%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;
6. At least one Android virtual device must be existent or an Android hardware device must be plugged in to the computer.

   Click on start->All programs->android SDK tools ->Launch avd manager

   Wait for it to open

   Fill in AVD NAME: for eg: SAMSUNG GALAXY, select Existing device and any target from the dropdown and click on OK.

   Android virtual device will be created.